# Python judgment that the input value is a null value

Tags: python

I designed a python program
After entering the grades of all students,
Minimum to maximum
I hope to rewrite the program as
When if the input value (score variable) is empty (when nothing is entered)
The program execution ends and the result of print is displayed.
**My problem is that I don't know how to write judgment grammar?
When if input input (score variable)
The value is a null value, the program execution ends, and the result of print is displayed**.
Program execution effect:

```
When judging the input (score variable), it is a null value
End the program execution and display the result of print

Please enter the student's grade: 89
Please enter the student's grade: 38
Please enter the student's grade: 49
Please enter the student's grade: 77
Please enter the student's grade: 448
Please enter the student's grade: 38
Please enter the student's grade: 39
Please enter the student's grade:
Grades are sorted from smallest to largest: [448 44, 55, 66, 88, 97, 22]
```

My code

```
 score=int(input("Please enter the student's score:"))
    mes = list()
    for i in range(1,8):
        score=int(input("Please enter the student's score:"))
        mes.sort()
        mes.append(score)
    print("Grades are sorted from smallest to largest", str(mes))
```

Hope can ask for help, thank you all

Comment: So basically you want the input numbers to be sorted in an ascending way?

Comment: I hope that when the program judges that the input value (score) variable is a null value, the program finishes execution and displays the result of print
The result of print sorts the grades of all students who have completed the input from smallest to largest

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your are looking for.

```
score = 0
grades = []

while score != "":
    score = input("Please enter the student's score:")
    if score != "":
        grades.append(score)

grades = sorted(grades)
print(f"Grades are sorted from smallest to largest: {grades}")
```